# Comparing row values SQL

Tags: mysql

I have at table which lists values for current month and previous month with Weekpart being WE(weekend) and WD(Weekdays)

```
Weekpart    Months  AvrgApps    AvrgOffers  AvrgDisbursements

WE          201509  441         259          40

WE          201508  432         235          40

WD          201508  2218        1591        334

WD          201509  2267        1156        346
```

I need to compare WD and WE values for the months and return 1 in column if current month value is higher than the previous month and 0 if its equal or lower than the previous month's value the result table would look something like

```
Weekpart Months AvrgApps AvrgOffers AvrgDisbursements
WE       201509 441          259         40

WE       201508 432          235         40

WD       201508 2218         1591        334

WD       201509 2267         1156        346

WE       201509 1             1          0

WD       201509 1             0          1
```

Comment: You wrote "if current month value is higher".  Higher than what, precisely? Please edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: Thanks. Edited. Hope the question is clear now.

Comment: Can you show me how the answer you want. Not getting the point from the question

Comment: why are you comparing wd & we if you are concern about months?

Comment: WE is for work done within the months but during Week ends. WD is for Work done during working days within the month. The first table in my question shows how the data looks now. The second table in the question has 1s and 0s, that's how it should look after the comparison. e.g For the month 201509 AvrgApps was 441 for WE and for month 201508 AvrgApps was 432 so AvrgApps returns 1

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like this?

```
SELECT  CONCAT(current.Months, '-', previous.Months) AS Months,
        IF(current.AvrgApps > previous.AvrgApps, 1, 0) AS AvrgApps,
        IF(current.AvrgOffers > previous.AvrgOffers, 1, 0) AS AvrgOffers,
        IF(current.AvrgDisbursements > previous.AvrgDisbursements, 1, 0) AS AvrgDisbursements
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM t
    WHERE Months = @current := (SELECT MAX(Months) FROM t)
) current
JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM t
    WHERE Months = (SELECT MAX(Months) FROM t WHERE Months < @current)
) previous ON current.Weekpart = previous.Weekpart
```

This will give you the month diff as results. I'm not sure you want to "union" it together with the data table.

Comment: Thanks let me see if I can make it work. I don't necessarily need to union